# Why doesn't my image load properly in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This is my original image:

[image]

But when I load it up on MATLAB and use imshow() on it, this is how I see it:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
I=imread('D:\Matty\pout.gif')
 imshow(I)
```

Comment: That is strange.... maybe try `imshow(im2double(I))`, or try to convert the image to another format before loading it '.jpg',... try to save the image from matlab `imwrite` (with another name), and see if it is modified.

Comment: @Oli Converting the image seemed to solve it. And Lucas pointed out the issue. Thanks for the reply. I'd have accepted your answer had you answered instead of commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIF is indexed format, and each image can have its own colormap. So you need to read the colormap together with the image:

```
[I, Imap] = imread('D:\Matty\pout.gif');
imshow(I,Imap)
```

I've tested it on your image and it works very well. i don't understand what was the problem @Lucas described in his answer.

Comment: I am not sure, but I also only have a pretty old version of Matlab (6.1) available at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Forget what I said earlier. It has to do with the colormap. The image seems to have a funky colormap. Generally you should be able to read the colormap with `[X, map] = imread(...)`, but there is some clipping of the data that I don't fully understand.

I copied the colormap manually out of the raw data from a hexeditor and saved it as `gif_colormap.txt`

> B1 B1 B1 AF AF AF AB AB AB A9 A9 A9 A7 A7 A7 A3 A3 A3 A1 A1 A1 9F 9F
>   9F 9D 9D 9D 9B 9B 9B 99 99 99 97 97 97 95 95 95 93 93 93 91 91 91 8F
>   8F 8F 8B 8B 8B 89 89 89 85 85 85 83 83 83 7F 7F 7F 7D 7D 7D 7B 7B 7B
>   79 79 79 77 77 77 75 75 75 71 71 71 6D 6D 6D 6B 6B 6B 69 69 69 67 67
>   67 65 65 65 63 63 63 61 61 61 5F 5F 5F 5D 5D 5D 5B 5B 5B 59 59 59 57
>   57 57 53 53 53 4D 4D 4D 4B 4B 4B E0 E0 E0 DC DC DC DA DA DA D6 D6 D6
>   D4 D4 D4 D2 D2 D2 D0 D0 D0 CE CE CE CC CC CC CA CA CA C8 C8 C8 C4 C4
>   C4 C2 C2 C2 C0 C0 C0 BE BE BE BA BA BA B8 B8 B8 B6 B6 B6 B4 B4 B4 B2
>   B2 B2 B0 B0 B0 AE AE AE AC AC AC AA AA AA A6 A6 A6 A4 A4 A4 A2 A2 A2
>   A0 A0 A0 9E 9E 9E 9C 9C 9C 9A 9A 9A 96 96 96 94 94 94 92 92 92 90 90
>   90 8E 8E 8E 8A 8A 8A 88 88 88 86 86 86 84 84 84 82 82 82 80 80 80 7E
>   7E 7E 7A 7A 7A 78 78 78 74 74 74 72 72 72 70 70 70 6E 6E 6E 6C 6C 6C
>   6A 6A 6A 66 66 66 62 62 62 5E 5E 5E 56 56 56 54 54 54 52 52 52 50 50
>   50 4E 4E 4E 4A 4A 4A DF DF DF DD DD DD DB DB DB D7 D7 D7 D5 D5 D5 D3
>   D3 D3 D1 D1 D1 CF CF CF CD CD CD C9 C9 C9 C7 C7 C7 C5 C5 C5 C3 C3 C3
>   C1 C1 C1 BD BD BD BB BB BB B9 B9 B9 B5 B5 B5 B3 B3 B3

Then I read in the new colormap and set it manually

```
fid = fopen('gif_colormap.txt', 'r')
A = fscanf(fid, '%x ');
fclose(fid);
my_map = reshape(A,3,121)'

im = imread('pout.gif');

%colormap has to be between 0 and 1
my_map = (my_map-min(my_map(:)))/max(my_map(:)); 

imshow(im,[])

%set colormap manually
colormap(my_map);
```

[image: result image of pouting girl]

Comment: Spot on. Thank you very much good Sir Lucas, that was nice piece of information :)