# Combining GIF images and colormaps to 3-D image arrays

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-conversion

When I read a color JPEG image:

```
jpgim = imread('path/to/image.jpg')
```

I get an MxNx3 array. However, with GIF files I also [need to read the colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295108/why-doesnt-my-image-load-properly-in-matlab):

```
[gifim, map] = imread('path/to/image2.gif')
```

Let's assume that I need only the first frame if the GIF image is animated: `gifim = gifim(:,:,:,1)` Is there a way to get a standard MxNx3 image array using `gifim` and `map` as that is what later parts of my processing pipeline expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html):

```
im = ind2rgb(gifim, map);
```